# How to know if Apple has received our appeal/how long does it take Apple to respond?

Tags: ios, app-store

My app was rejected. We appealed one week ago this Friday, including documentation and some screen shots.

We have heard nothing back yet. I received an email that they did receive the appeal.

How long does Apple take to review an appeal?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Apple support and not an on-topic programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the apple review team responds in 24 to 48 hours after appealing. Although this time may vary depends on the complexity of your case.

My suggestion is do not ping them too much & if you have submitted an appeal. Keep it patient & wait for at least few days. They will surely respond on time.

Another most important thing is you should keep using good & kind language tone while communicating to the review team. Other wise it can be the worst case & you can get your account suspension.

So my suggestion is be kind & patient.

**Important Note :**

- This suggestions I am giving based on my past experience just to make sure anyone could not face such weird issue again.
- What happened in my case was my application was not getting into review since more than 20 days. I kept messaging them & asking about the status. I even appealed them why it's getting much delayed. Every time I got response like review team is working hard & your app will be reviewed soon.
- At one stage I loose my temper & I have given them examples of the other publishers who get their apps live even after they have uploaded their apps. Apple review team found this behaviour bit rude & sadly it ended up with suspension of my account permanently. It was a huge loss as there was few live stable apps all got removed from store due to suspension.

Hope this helps to everyone.

Comment: Thank you Mayur I very much appreciate your feedback.